# Order the data in SQL in the below format in SQL with using of inline or sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the data in the below format :-

```
Name    Sex
A   F
B   F
C   F
D   F
E   M
F   M
G   M
X   F
SQ  F
DS  M
SW  M
QA  F
SA  F
```

Need to convert in this format :-

```
A   F
DS  M
B   F
SW  M
C   F
E   M
D   F
F   M
X   F
G   M
SQ  F
QA  F
SA  F
```

I have the query which does it but need to know any other method of doing it

```
Select * 
from test_gender
order by ROW_NUMBER () Over (Partition by Sex order by Sex), Sex
```

with help of a subquery.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Can you advise on what the pattern of ordering is? It looks fairly arbitrary to me? Or is the idea a best effort interleave of one F, one M, alphabetically, until we run out of data? But then why is `SW  M` ahead of `E M`?

Comment: What is the issue with your method?  It seems like a good method to me.